# how to find how deep an element is nested in jquery

Tags: jquery

Say I had something like this:

```
<ul id='B'>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li id='A'></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And I wanted to find out how far I needed to go to get from a-b.. and i wanted the number of parents I needed to go down returned as a number. How would I achieve it??

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

`$('#B').parentsUntil('#A').length + 1; // last 1 because we're going until '#A'`

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yW2Vv/1/)***

Read more about ***[.parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)***

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var parent = $('#A').parent();
var count = 1;

while ('B' != parent.attr('id')) {
    parent = parent.parent();
    ++count;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/yW2Vv/