# How to get current element depth in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider I have HTML

```
<div id=test> 
    <a>test1</a>

    <div> 
        <a>test2</a>
        <a>test3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 2nd & 3rd links are in different depth than the first one, and if I use jQuery to select them, how to identify their difference in depth?

```
$('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text() + " and my current depth is: "); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpp8d/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710943/js-jquery-get-depth-of-element, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509707/how-to-find-how-deep-an-element-is-nested-in-jquery

Comment: Your question has been closed , so i put my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24058845/747579

Answer (score 4):

I'd do this using `$(this).parents().length`

http://jsfiddle.net/vpp8d/1/

Comment: I'd suggest using `parentsUntil('body')` (the 'depth' probably shouldn't include `<body>` or `<html>` elements): [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vpp8d/3/).

Comment: Why do You assume it shouldnt contain body? If the function is needed to depth comparison only - it does not matter. If not, You can always just decrement result by 2 : ]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get depth *within a specific container*, use [`parentsUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text() + " and my current depth is: " + $(this).parentsUntil('#test').length);  // 0, 1, 1 in your case
});
```

[`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) will return the depth relative to root element, which is probably not what you want.